# Sorting a Python Dictionary by Priority

Tags: python, sorting, python-3.7

I have a python dictionary consisting of (names,value) pairs like so

```
pyDictionary = {"Bob":12,"Mellissa":12,"roger":13}
```

What i would like to do is to obtain a sorted version of the above dictionary where the sorting is done by giving first prority to the value and if the value for two pairs are the same then the comparision should be made by lexographically comparing the names.

How can i acheive this in python3.7?

Comment: Don't use `dict` as a variable name, since doing so overrides the standard definition.

Comment: Notice that order in python dictionaries is random. If you want to sort dictionary use `OrderedDict` from collections

Comment: @TomKarzes My Apologies I am new to the community

Comment: @Relandom The OP specifically states that the question is for Python 3.7, where the order of dict keys are preserved.

Comment: @AtifFarooq No need to apologize - it's just a Python tip :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `sorted`  with a `key`, and build an [`OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) from the result to mantain order.

(the last step is only necessary with python `3.6 <`, in Python 3.7 dicts are ordered on their key insertion time)

---

```
from collections import OrderedDict
d = {"Mellissa":12, "roger":13, "Bob":12}

OrderedDict(sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x: (x[1], x[0])))
# dict(sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x: (x[1], x[0]))) # for Python 3.7
# [('Bob', 12), ('Mellissa', 12), ('roger', 13)]
```

---

Or you can also use [`operator.itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html) to directly fetch the `value` and `key` from each tuple respectively:

```
OrderedDict(sorted(d.items(), key=itemgetter(1,0)))
# dict(sorted(d.items(), key=itemgetter(1,0))) # python 3.7
# [('Bob', 12), ('Mellissa', 12), ('roger', 13)]
```

Comment: In *Python 3.7* *dict*s are ordered on their key insertion time.

Comment: Yes @CristiFati added a comment in the solution

Comment: What if i want to sort the first column in Descending but the second in ascending order can this solution be extended to this new scenario?

Comment: You mean the key from a to z and values descending @AtifFarooq ?

Comment: Use `dict(sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x: (-x[1], x[0])))`

Comment: @yatu Thanks i figured it out on my own but thanks for your reponse !

Answer (score 2):

You can sort the dict items with a key function that reverses the order of the key-value tuple:

```
dict(sorted(pyDictionary.items(), key=lambda t: t[::-1]))
```

Comment: What about [**`reversed`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#reversed)?

Comment: `reversed` won't work because it returns an iterable, which is not comparable.